# Meteor collection get previous and next item

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to get the previous and next item in a collection. Below is what I have tried, but it is not working. I get results, but they are not returning in the correct order. Any suggestions?

Previous:

```
 Meteor.videos.find({$lt: currentID}, {sort: {date: -1}, limit:1});
```

Next:

```
Meteor.videos.find({$gt: currentID}, {sort: {date: -1}, limit:1});
```

Answer (score 8):

Try querying on the date, rather than document ID.

```
var current = Meteor.videos.findOne(currentID);
```

Previous:

```
Meteor.videos.find({date: {$lt: current.date}}, {sort: {date: -1}, limit:1});
```

Next:

```
Meteor.videos.find({date: {$gt: current.date}}, {sort: {date: 1}, limit:1});
```

You also need to sort the next cursor in ascending order.

Comment: This did not quite work. I had to modify the code, but I am not getting a random document back. Meteor.videos.find({date:{$gt: current.date}}, {sort: {date: 1}, limit:1}).fetch()[0];

Comment: I forgot the most important part! Fixed now.